# Is it possible to add an app which requires VPN connection to be run for TestFlight?

Tags: ios, vpn, testflight, review

Is it possible to add an app for TestFlight, but to run this app a VPN is necessary? Our PRD environment will be public of course, but we want to test UAT version, which for security reasons have to point to local URLs. It is only about TestFlight review.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Do you wish to release it for internal testers or externals?

Comment: @NimeshNeema We have a plan to do testing on small group of our friends, but I can't guarantee the future steps. Is this important? Could you answer for both cases?

Comment: What's the approximate size of the group? If the total count is under 25, prefer going with internal testers, as it doesn't involve getting the app approved by Apple for beta release via TestFlight, and the app is available to release to testers via TestFlight almost instantly after uploading on App Store Connect. Details here: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: @NimeshNeema I've got an info that we need this tests only for internal use (UAT/TST). So it will be very limited number of testers (10-20).

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add an app for TestFlight, but to run this app a VPN is necessary?

You should be fine. An app requiring VPN to function wouldn't be a reason for it to not be allowed for testing via TestFlight or even distribution via App Store.

There's no clause in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) that would prevent you from distributing such an app.

As far as distribution for testing via TestFlight is concerned, you can choose to distribute it internally or external (See the comparison between internal and external testers here: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

Basically with internal testers, you'd be able to release an app for testing as soon as you upload on App Store Connect. But the number of internal testers is limited to 25 users (25 Apple IDs, where each user can install the app on a maximum of upto 10 devices each).

With external testers the upper limit is 1000 users (with upto 10 devices each user), but an app distributed to external testers needs to go through an approval process through Apple.